# Do 3D ear impression scanners yield higher quality custom flat-response attenuators compared to traditional ear impression techniques (eg, spleading)?

Tags: equipment, health, hearing

I am getting a new pairs of flat-response attenuators (a.k.a., "musician earplugs"). Do 3D ear impression scanners yield higher quality custom-molded flat-response attenuators compared to traditional ear impression techniques (e.g., [spleading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTmgf.jpg) (source: Westone Earpiece Guide 2022))?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about music practice or theory.

Comment: @PiedPiper it's a question about music equipment, which is on-topic.

Comment: To me this is borderline leaning towards off-topic, but I'll let the community decide. The reason is we don't allow questions around generic sound equipment outside of the practice of music. Another analogus example is if you wanted answers on a home audio system amp or speakers while there are other amp and speaker questions here, they fall outside of our general expertise. See https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/831/7222.

Comment: @Dom Thanks, I see, I'd argue that flat-response attenuators are typically purchased by music practitioners, whereas home audio system amp or speakers are typically purchased by anyone.

Comment: Something that definitely is used primarily by musicians are moulded in-ear monitors. Perhaps the question would be less controversial if it included those.

Comment: A question about something used by musicians to protect their hearing seems legitimate to me. The problem is can anyone provide a knowledgeable answer here? It seems to me like someone would have to have experience with both types of attenuators to do that.

Comment: As far as I can tell it’s not even different types of attenuators but different way to create the ear model they are based on. My experience is that there’s nothing left to be improved in traditionally molded set, but the process itself was slow and uncomfortable.

Comment: @ojs thanks, yes, it's the same type of attenuators, just different way to create the ear impression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3D scanning may produce a more accurate mold of the human ear but the quality of an in-ear impression (spleading) depends on the skill of the person.

3D scanning is less messy and more comfortable, but I have found no practical (performance) difference in the quality of the attenuators produced by the two techniques. The quality of the lab making the attenuators is a greater consideration.

So go with the method that is most economical and practical for you.

Comment: @Downvoter: Why the downvote?